# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure in GCP - CloudSQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect my spring boot jar with google cloud SQL (MySQL 5.7, mysql-connector 8.0.18) database. I am deploying my jar in a centos 7 VM in gcp.

When I started the server, I got the above mentioned error. the stack trace is

This error comes in the machine with java version openjdk-1.8.0_292. But I have another machine with java version as openjdk-1.8.0_282 everything works completely fine.

connection details in property file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<<ipaddress>>:3306/<<schema>>
spring.datasource.username=<<uname>>
spring.datasource.password=<<password>>
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Not able to get what is the issue here. Any help will be appreciated

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.app.provisioning.ProvisioningApplication.main(ProvisioningServiceApplication.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:338)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:428)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:316)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:329)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
2021-05-18 07:36:50 ERROR [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your `jdbc://` connection string, editing out any username or password of course.

Comment: Are you using the Cloud SQL Proxy? If not is the IP address of your system whitelisted? The stack trace appears to be a connection timeout issue.

Comment: @JohnHanley, if it was an connection times out issue, it should have been mentioned in the trace. I am able to connect the same DB from a different machine with that 1.8.0_282 java version

Comment: `The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.`

Comment: @O.Jones, I have updated as you asked

Comment: @JohnHanley, please see the full trace below that, it would say connect timed out not that SSL error. And I am able to connect this db from different machines

Comment: I do not have a crystal ball for every problem, but I have been working with Cloud SQL since it was pre-alpha. The fact that you can connect from another machine may or may not be relevant. However, if the server is not returning a response, then the SSL connection error might be pointing to the underlying problem (tcp connection error). Why is your client connecting with SSL? I do not see SSL configured in your question. Did you whitelist your IP address? Have you tried using the CLI to connect? Have you tried using the SQL Proxy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232675/discussion-between-smootherbug-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Edit your question with the suggestions that I asked. Once a question requires going to chat, you should delete and start over as the details required to answer your question are not present.

Comment: I did not mean to be disrespectful. Its just my understanding because I have seen that error for connection timed out.
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
i am not aware of this one though

Comment: what I tried is i have 2 cloudsql dbs, I connected from 2 centos machines with different java versions as mentioned above, whitelisted ips for both machines in both dbs. and when I started my server, one machine was able to connect and the other returned that exception above,
the only difference between those 2 machines was the java version and nothing else

Comment: Why is your client connecting via SSL? That configuration is not present in your question. Update your question to show the real connection detail including the code. If the server is not responding, of course, the handshake will fail.

Comment: there is no SSL configuration in my centos VM, but not sure why that error comes though

Comment: You have too many unknowns. Stop and review your setup and your code. The only reason your Java code would connect to Cloud SQL via SSL is if your code is configured to do so. If you do not know why, then stop and figure out why.

Comment: Have you set Cloud SQL to "require" SSL connections?

Comment: No, that is not checked

Comment: The  issue is because of this reason,
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/tls-1-0-1-1-changes-in-openjdk-and-amazon-corretto/. openjdk has disabled tls 1.0 and tls1.1 from the 1.8.0_292 version. But couldn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got the same problem with you, and then I saw the comments below to know it was caused by the new version of openJDK.
So thank you that you give me a direction to survey this problem.

Now I fixed the problem, there are three solution to fix:

1. set useSSL=false

Just add **?useSSL=false** after your `spring.datasource.url`

But the solution break the security.

Because my project use the local web, so I use this solution.

Work like a charm :)

2. remove SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 in java.security

Try to find your java.security

https://mkyong.com/java/where-is-the-java-security-file/

Then edit it, and try to find jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms.

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

Remove SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, then save and restart the project.

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

3. Install the old version jdk
   Just like you said on comments, the old version work fine.
   But It seem not be a good solution.

I hole that would be useful for you.